# how to resolve exception in jdo query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jdo

I'm developing an application with gwt and google app engine and I have a problem with run jdo query.

I run jdo query and get an exception like this:

> Splitting the provided query requires that too many subqueries are merged in memory.

I have the table of Building that like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Building{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key key ;
 @Persistent
 private Boolean active;
 @Persistent
 private String description;
 @Persistent
 private String address;

 and more params....
}
```

I have another table of service call like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")
public class ServiceCall {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key key ;
 @Persistent
 protected String buildingKey;
 @Persistent
 private Date dueDateReminder;
 @Persistent
 private String reporterKeyPath;
 @Persistent
 private String reporterName;
 @Persistent
 private Integer status;

 and more params....
}
```

Every service call is related to a building with a buildingKey param in the serviceCall table.

I want to select 10 service call orders by dueDateReminder column and related to 50 kind of buildings so I tried to run query like this:

```
SELECT FROM com.lebsh.floor.server.jdo.ServiceCall 
WHERE (((buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6109986115551232)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4794970208731136)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4557475697131520)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5677878045835264)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4690516604092416)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5199590487752704)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6564084417822720)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4689417092464640)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4765283394781184)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4716904883159040)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5020370092425216)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5586618580729856)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5196291952869376)') ||
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6616860975955968)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4554177162248192)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(4597058115731456)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5825212603957248)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5033564231958528)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5372213813313536)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5875790138834944)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5481065464463360)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5222680231936000)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5952755952779264)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6694926301528064)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6234230929489920)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5032464720330752)') || 
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(5693271208624128)') || 
    ... (many many more similar clauses) ||
    (buildingKey == 'BUILDING(6699324348039168)'))  && 
    ((dueDateReminder <= Date0)))
PARAMETERS Date Date0 import java.util.Date 
ORDER BY dueDateReminder  ASCENDING RANGE 0,10
```

I understand why I get exception but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: When dealing with databases that are not very capable (GAE/Datastore) you have to take on the burden of merging things in your own code. Split the query into (a few) smaller queries and merge them in Java code. Or use a decent database

Comment: Hii thank you for replay. unfortunatly this solution is not good for me the problem is that i need my results sorted so if i write 3 diffrents queries then i have to sort the 3 results in code. is there any other solution you can think of? i read about the operator IN (inorder to replace the or operator) but i dont understand hot to use it. if you know this operator and if you think it can help me i would like an explnation about it

Comment: Does GAE/Datastore support IN ? And even if it does, does Googles DataNucleus plugin support it ? Google don't support it, so doubt you'll get an answer other than looking at the code for it. That aside you can easily order objects in a List using a Comparator (trivial).

Comment: thank you for replay. so i try to split the query to 3 queries and get the 10 service calls and use comparator